# Create a custom template for displaying a custom content type - and Views in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, views, theming, nodes

I'm creating custom templates for my Drupal 7 site. There is a custom **content type** called `flowers`.

1. Which **template** file (`.tpl.php`) should I put under `templates` directory of my theme's folder for displaying a single `flower-type` node?
2. Can I use the `Views` module to create different views *(i.e displaying picture of a flower in a view & displaying species of the flower in another view)* for displaying **only a single** `flower-type` node? So far I can create pages that displays *list* of flower-type nodes. I want to display *just a single* (perhaps providing it's node-id) `flower-type` node. How do I do that?

   2.1. For displaying different types of views to display a single flower-type node, which **template files** (`.tpl.php`) should I edit?

Thanks in advance for caring :)

Answer (score 4):

Create node--flowers.tpl.php, put the default code from modules/node/node.tpl.php, and edit it.

Comment: Thanks @ram4nd. Would you please take some time and answer the 2nd problem  - creating Views using `Views` module to display just one flower? 

Thanks

Comment: You can do this under pager settings. Instead of pager select display specific number of items. And you can configure the number of displayed items and offset.

Comment: Your answer is incomplete, so I answered it after creating a fully detailed tutorial on my blog. Thanks & +1 for helping